# Fetching entire row from CSV using the specific column values mentioned in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to fetch  complete specific rows from CSV, based on the specific column values. The specific column values are mentioned in a list

Example, I have list:

A = [4,9,11], the values within A represent the case IDs.

My csv look like shown in attached picture

[The first column within the CSV is case ID. we should refer to this column, in order to fetch the specific rows using case IDs mentioned in list A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWYPJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,3)))

df['first'] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

df.set_index('first',inplace=True)

df
```

```
#OUTPUT
    0   1   2
first           
1   0.664272    0.243433    0.767825
2   0.779404    0.663445    0.014866
3   0.011077    0.083237    0.023290
4   0.252047    0.235671    0.526924
5   0.166838    0.869083    0.878226
```

```
df.loc[[1,3,4]]
```

```
# OUTPUT
0   1   2
first           
1   0.664272    0.243433    0.767825
3   0.011077    0.083237    0.023290
4   0.252047    0.235671    0.526924
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but you can get the line where the specific value resides.

Using this CSV:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
```

This code will find the line with the id you search.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('Untitled.csv', delimiter=',')

id = 18

for lineno, line in enumerate(my_data):
    if id in line:
        print(my_data[lineno])
```